# Array not complete in PHP session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have had a confusing problems for a few days. I store an array with 10 - 50 elements in the session array.

```
$_SESSION['my_array'] = erg_array;
```

Then I submit a form to another page. On the new page I read the array and only a few elements are left in the array. Sometimes there are 2 or 3 or 4 elements in the array.

If I look in the session file on the Server, the array is not complete in the file. At the end of my page I check the array

```
print_r($_SESSION['my_array']);
```

and 50 elements will be printed. That is the last line of code. In my session-server file are only 3 elements stored.

Has anybody an idea where to look?

---

Edit:

If I serialize my array like this

```
$_SESSION['my_array_string'] = base64_encode(serialize($_SESSION['my_array'));
```

and on the other script

```
$_SESSION['my_array'] = unserialize(base64_decode($_SESSION['my_array_string']));
```

the array is complete?

Comment: I don't know, how is it possible. But i can tell you the alternate if you tell me what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to store articledata in the session an transfer it to the other scripts. that worked well since the last 3 years. now i have the problem with the session. i know some alternates like storing in file or db ... but i want to know what the prob is ?

Comment: You sir have a very interesting(annoying) problem. Can you provide us with some code samples so we can replicate? Also tell us your hosting setup?

Comment: i use a managed Server from 1und1. with PHP 5.2.17 and Linux

Comment: Do you have any object from custom classes on your array ?

Comment: no, only values from a db select - no objects

Comment: **The session is loaded into memory at run time - so it's limited by the memory_limit in php.ini**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store $_SESSION['my_array'] array in variable before serializing it. Like this...

$array[] = $_SESSION['my_array'];
Here array gets stores in array variable, now serialize that array to new session.

$_SESSION['my_array_string'] = base64_encode(serialize($array[]));

This may solve out your problem.